# Why does Admiral James Norrington ultimately side with the pirates?

Tags: character, pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

I will always stand with Sparrow and his forces... but what did Admiral Norrington see in them in *Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End*? He had a decent rank working for Beckett aboard the HMS Endeavor.

"But he had always been too good for them..." that is what someone said to me the other day. Then why did he not switch sides sooner? Or at least have become a spy? That would have been a real joke on Beckett!

It breaks my heart to watch him finally decide with whom his loyalties lie (the kissing scene between him and Elizabeth makes me cry) and then Bootstrap kills him... I guess fate truly does intervene... Beckett was right for once... WHY!?

Comment: Long story short, He has no loyalty to Beckett, He loved his duty as Commodore, but after East India trading company takes over, his life was not a happy one. And main reason would be his love towards Elizabeth. Norrington **did not take pirate's side, But he did take** Elizebeth's **side**

Comment: i agree completely. I just wish that he would have taken sides sooner. I also wish that bootstrap would not have stabbed him... if he had not been that cursed, he would have kept his head...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because James felt there was honor & duty in serving the British Royal Navy (reinstated later by East Indian Co.). --But the only thing missing from his life was someone he "loved".

Ultimately, he loved Elizabeth and his belief system and morality is contested when Elizabeth reveals to James, that Beckett had her father killed, proving the institutions he once believed in, are now wrong (without honor).

Note: Norrington represents a dichotomy featured in the series about the order (Government-Military - Security) vs freedom (or Imperialism vs Piracy) AND themes of unrequited/disrupted love stories.

**At World's End Transcript: (Note: The KISS)**

> Norrington [to Elizabeth]: Come with me. [she doesn’t move] Quickly!
>   [she nods to crew and they exit]
>
> Elizabeth: What are you doing?
>
> Norrington: Choosing a side. [Elizabeth exits cell. Bootstrap sees
>   empty cell and looks around.] Do not go to Shipwreck Cove. Beckett
>   knows of the meeting of the Brethren. I fear there may be a traitor
>   among them.
>
> Elizabeth: It’s too late to earn my forgiveness.
>
> Norrington: **I had nothing to do with your father’s death. That doesn’t
>   absolve me of my other sins**.
>
> Elizabeth: Come with us. James, come with me.
>   enter Bootstrap]
>
> Bootstrap: Who goes there?
>
> Norrington [to Elizabeth]: Go. I will follow.
>
> Elizabeth: You’re lying.
>
> Norrington: **Our destinies have been entwined, Elizabeth... but never
>   joined.** [kisses her] Go! Now! [to Bootstrap] Back to your station,
>   sailor.

**Confirmed by POTC Wikipedia:**

> Despite having got what he wanted, **Norrington came to regret his
>   previous actions upon learning of Beckett's hand in Governor Swann's
>   death**, which he learned from Elizabeth after capturing the Empress. In
>   the end, Norrington had to make a choice and choose a side. Norrington
>   gave up everything, including his life, **to help Elizabeth** and her 
>    crew escape from the Flying Dutchman.

---

> Among those gathered was Elizabeth Swann, whom Norrington had first
>   met on the crossing from England, and had developed a friendship with
>   over the past eight years. **However, Norrington was also in love with
>   Elizabeth**, and, since he believed a wife was the only thing missing in
>   his life, wished for her hand in marriage.
>   http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/James_Norrington

Comment: WHY IS EVERYONE IN LOVE WITH ELIZABETH???!!! Honestly, man... I guess that since she is the princess of the situation... her and then a ton of men surrounding her... Will is super lucky to have won her heart, there are tons of guys in line behind him!

Comment: Not everyone, just 3 characters! ;)

Comment: I guess... it is just not all women are that lucky (sigh) I have a few paparazzis myself, but... nevertheless, Elizabeth is quite unique and special

Comment: @TurtleyAwesome Elizabeth is the only *lady* in the movies, so it's not much of a competition. She was clean, pretty and as word means, she's a lady. Hence the attraction. Regarding this quote from you, **Elizabeth is quite unique and special**, I'm not gonna trust her though, nor should anyone except Will ;)